# Query most recent TWO entries per widget

Tags: sql, ms-access, date

I have two tables.  One (Widgets) has a list of widgets (ID, widget_name, color, etc...) and data about them.
The other one (Tests) has a list of tests run on the widgets (ID, date, info1, info2, etc...).

What I want to do is display the most recent TWO tests. I dont think i really need to use the table Widgets for this but i described it so you would know where im coming from.

I have constructed a "Totals" query that uses the MAX() function and displays the single most recent Date for each ID. I then can use this query to construct another query that displays useful information about the test that happened on that date for that widget.  What i really need, though is to have the most recent two test dates for each widget.

Comment: PS: there is a one to many relationship between Widgets and Tests.  In other words,  there are many rows for each ID in Tests.  Each test takes a row and is associated with a particular date.  Now i feel like im talking too much so ill stop.

Comment: You can edit your own question -- you don't need to add a comment to alter it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need the two most recent tests overall, then

```
Select * From Tests T
Where (Select Count(*) From tests
       Where testDate > T.TestDate) < 2
```

If you need the two most recent tests for each Widget, then

```
Select * From Tests T
Where (Select Count(*) From tests
       Where WidgetId = T.WidgetId 
           And testDate > T.TestDate) < 2
```

Comment: i dont know if my comment got through.  it worked!  thanks a ton

Answer (score 0):

(assuming all dates for the same widget are unique)

```
select T.*
from Widget W
join Test T on T.widget_id = W.id
where T.date >= (
    select max(T2.date)
    from Test T2
    where T2.widget_id = W.id
    and T2.date < (
        select max(T3.date)
        from Test T3
        where T3.widget_id = W.id
    )
) 
or T.date == (
    select max(T2.date)
    from Test T2
    where T2.widget_id = W.id
)
```