# sql most recent two records filtered on date

Tags: sql, sql-server, date

So I have a table that logs request made.
the table is as follows:

```
Id  SiteId  StartedAt               FinishedAt              Url
1   2926    2015-08-10 14:53:00.230 2015-08-10 14:53:02.890 https://site1.com/Index.aspx
2   2928    2015-08-10 14:52:57.190 2015-08-10 14:53:33.107 https://site2.com/Admin/Index.aspx
3   2926    2015-08-10 14:53:02.897 2015-08-10 14:53:25.177 https://site1.com
4   2926    2015-08-10 14:53:02.897 2015-08-10 14:53:48.647 https://site2.com?ID=1
5   2926    2015-08-10 14:53:02.900 2015-08-10 14:53:48.947 https://site1.com/Tab?id=1
6   2926    2015-08-10 14:53:02.900 2015-08-10 14:53:48.377 https://site2.com/5
```

I need to display these request in a **Last Request** and **Previous Request** manner. See image below.

[image]

So I'm trying to select the two most recent request made for any individual URL and I can get that working. See: [Query most recent TWO entries per widget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1395991/query-most-recent-two-entries-per-widget).

However this list that I'm using to display the request in has a date picker. So the user could select say 8/12/2015 and that would be selecting all **Last Request** that started on that day and each of those request would then show **previous request**, that may not necessarily fall on the selected day, and the difference between the two.

One row of the above markup would equate to two rows of my SQL output. So for every unique URL I get 2 rows. Representing the latest request and the one right before it.

So here's where I'm currently at:

```
SELECT [Id], [FK_SiteId] as SiteId, [StartedAt],[FinishedAt],[Url]
FROM SiteWarmupMetrics sw
WHERE (Select Count(*) From SiteWarmupMetrics s
       Where sw.Url = s.Url
       AND s.StartedAt > sw.StartedAt) < 2  
       AND SUBSTRING(Url, CHARINDEX ('/', Url, 9), 500) = '/Index.aspx'                         
ORDER BY sw.Url, sw.StartedAt
```

Now I tried adding `AND CONVERT(DATE, s.StartedAt) = '2015-08-10'` but its not quite working. I feel I'm close just missing something.

So here's the result I'm trying to get, but with a query that takes in a date:

```
Id  SiteId  StartedAt                FinishedAt               Url
20  2928    2015-08-10 16:12:39.430 2015-08-10 16:13:14.157 https://site1.com/Index.aspx
38  2928    2015-08-12 11:22:46.593 2015-08-12 11:23:16.183 https://site1.com/Index.aspx
19  2926    2015-08-10 16:12:39.430 2015-08-10 16:12:45.207 https://site2.com/Index.aspx
37  2926    2015-08-12 11:22:46.587 2015-08-12 11:22:52.030 https://site2.com/Index.aspx
```

Comment: Could you post a http://sqlfiddle.com/ with your table structure and data please?

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using?  The latest versions have "window" functions that let you access the previous row more easily, which might prove useful... as long as you can guarantee running on SQL2014 or later only.

Comment: unfortunately I'm running it on SQL 2008

Comment: Why is your desired result in seconds (33s)?    33 seconds from what?   Or do you want the result as shown in your final code sample (totally different columns)?   Which is it?

Comment: Do you want first and last, or last and the one before? the image is first and last (@TabAlleman I believe 33s is the time difference between startedAt and FinishedAt)

Comment: @TabAlleman That's just some quick markup, The desired sql output is at the bottom. One row of that markup would equate to two rows of my SQL output. So for every site I get 2 rows. Representing the latest request and the one right before it.

Comment: @ZoharPeled, yes, I want the last and the one before it.

Comment: so... `select top 2 ....from....where.... order by .... desc`?

Comment: @ZoharPeled: That would work for the results of one site as the top 2 would limit it. I would need a query that gets the last two for every unique Url.

Comment: every unique url or every unique site id? I recommend editing your question to make it clearer.

Comment: Ok, I believe I have posted the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tab was close, need to Partition By Url and not SiteID.  Also, the union in the select is not necessary, instead select rows with ROW_NUMBER() <= 2, so it will grab the first two results from the cte.

```
DECLARE @FromDate DATETIME = '2015-08-10'
;WITH cte AS (
  SELECT [Id], [FK_SiteId] as SiteId, [StartedAt],[FinishedAt],[Url],
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Url ORDER BY StartedAt DESC) AS rn
  FROM SiteWarmupMetrics
  WHERE CONVERT(DATE, StartedAt) <= CONVERT(Date, @FromDate)
)
SELECT [Id], SiteId, [StartedAt],[FinishedAt],[Url]
FROM cte WHERE cte.Rn <= 2
```

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server 2008 doesn't have the LAG function, but it does have ROW_NUMBER().

To get the results in your last code sample, and assuming you pass the user's date picker selection as a parameter called `@FromDate` this should do the trick:

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT [Id], [FK_SiteId] as SiteId, [StartedAt],[FinishedAt],[Url]
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY FK_SiteId ORDER BY StartedAt DESC) AS rn
  FROM SiteWarmupMetrics
  WHERE StartedAt >= @FromDate
)
SELECT [Id], SiteId, [StartedAt],[FinishedAt],[Url]
FROM cte
WHERE rn=1
UNION ALL
SELECT s1.[Id], s1.FK_SiteId AS SiteId, s1.[StartedAt],s1.[FinishedAt],s1.[Url]
FROM cte 
LEFT OUTER JOIN SiteWarmupMetrics s1
  ON cte.[Id]=(
    SELECT TOP 1 [Id]
    FROM SiteWarmupMetrics s2
    WHERE cte.SiteId=s2.FK_SiteId
    AND s2.StartedAt < cte.StartedAt
    ORDER BY s2.StartedAt DESC
  )
WHERE cte.rn=1
ORDER BY SiteId, StartedAt
```

EDIT:   My first attempt was confounded by the need to get the first row AFTER the FromDate parameter, but then the row BEFORE that, which could be either before or after the parameter.   My current query should solve for that as well.