# My query displays 'n' most recent dates in one column over 'n' rows for each name. I would like 'n' recent dates columns for each name

Tags: sql, date, ms-access

For my specific case, n = 4, but may one day need to be n=5 or n=6.

Top level description of what I need: I have a form which allows me to add names and dates to a jump log. I need to build a query that will display the four most recent jumps for each jumper, with a column for each date.

My form stores the data in the "JUMP" table which has 3 fields: JUMPID, NAME, DATE. Sample data looks like this:

```
JUMPID   NAME   DATE
1        Joe    01-Jul-16
2        Joe    15-Jul-16
3        Adam   15-Jul-16
4        Joe    26-Jul-16
5        Ryan   28-Jul-16
6        Adam   02-Aug-16
7        Joe    10-Aug-16
8        Adam   10-Aug-16
9        Joe    12-Aug-16
10       Mike   19-Aug-16
11       Joe    19-Aug-16
12       Mike   19-Aug-16
13       Dave   19-Aug-16
14       Ryan   23-Aug-16
```

The query I am using now returns the 4 most recent jumps for each jumper, but stores all of the dates in the same column. The query is:

```
Select NAME, [DATE]
From [JUMP]
Where DATE In
   (Select Top 4 [DATE]
    From [JUMP] jum
    Where [JUMP].[NAME] = jum.[NAME]
    Order By jum.[DATE] DESC;)
Order By NAME, [DATE] DESC;
```

The output from this query is displayed like this:

```
NAME    DATE
Adam    10-Aug-16
Adam    02-Aug-16
Adam    15-Jul-16
Dave    19-Aug-16
Joe     19-Aug-16
Joe     12-Aug-16
Joe     10-Aug-16
Joe     26-Jul-16
Mike    19-Aug-16
Mike    19-Aug-16
Ryan    23-Aug-16
Ryan    28-Jul-16
```

What I want is for these 4 most recent jumps to each have their own column, like this:

```
NAME    RECENT1     RECENT2     RECENT3     RECENT4
Adam    10-Aug-16   02-Aug-16   15-Jul-16
Dave    19-Aug-16
Joe     19-Aug-16   12-Aug-16   10-Aug-16   26-Jul-16
Mike    19-Aug-16   19-Aug-16
Ryan    23-Aug-16   28-Jul-16
```

Duplicate dates are fine, as the same jumper may jump more than once in a day. Empty, or null, fields are fine for dates for jumpers that have fewer than 4 jumps.

I've gotten halfway there through the use of google which helped me build the query found above. Any help in reaching my preferred end state would be very much appreciated.

Comment: I removed the incompatible database tags.  Please add the tag for the database you are really using.

Comment: This is being used in MS Access 2007, which is why I added the access tag. I wasn't sure about the MySQL tag.

Comment: You need sql for pivot. A lot of examples could be found here or just googled. MS Access specifically has TRANSFORM

Comment: I'm a bit of a novice when it comes to SQL and Access in general. Have literally been learning as I go. I will start looking for solutions via the Transform method. Thanks for the input.

Answer (score 1):

I spent several hours trying to solve my problem using the TRANSFORM...PIVOT method in MS Access as suggested by Serg with no success. I think this was mainly due to lacking an additional field that would classify each jump as recent 1, 2, 3, 4, or no longer tracking. I can't think of a way in which this would be done without updating this field for each jumper's records every time they jump. I may be wrong in this, I'm not sure, because again, I'm no expert. If there is a way to assign a value of 1, 2, 3, 4 to each jump that my original query returned as a calculated field (?), I'd be in business with the TRANSFORM method.

That said, I did find a solution that mostly works, but is clunky, in my opinion. I say mostly because it breaks if a jumper jumps more than once in a day. My partial solution involved creating 4 separate queries to identify the first, second, third, and fourth most recent jumps, respectively, and then combining those 4 queries into a final query.

The four queries look like this:

```
Select NAME, DATE
From JUMP As jum
Where (
       Select Count(NAME)
       From JUMP
       Where NAME = jum.NAME
       AND DATE > jum.DATE) = 0;   (0 gives me most recent, 1 second most recent, etc.)
```

Credit for this query goes to [Charles Bretana](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1395991/query-most-recent-two-entries-per-widget?rq=1) on this stackoverflow question. I don't really understand how it does what it does, but it works for what I need except when there is more than one jump for a jumper.

Using these 4 queries I then constructed another query which combines the 4 into 1. This query looks like this:

```
SELECT Query1.NAME, Query1.DATE, Query2.DATE, Query3.DATE, Query4.DATE
FROM ((Query2 RIGHT JOIN Query1 ON Query2.NAME=Query1.NAME)
       LEFT JOIN Query3 ON Query1.NAME = Query3.NAME)
       LEFT JOIN Query4 ON Query1.NAME = Query4.NAME
ORDER BY query1.NAME;
```

This gives me the data in the format that I need it in: rows with names and 4 columns, one each for 1st/2nd/3rd/4th most recent jumps, but breaks when there is a jumper with more than one jump in a day. Using the original sample data above, the resulting datasheet looks like this:

```
NAME    RECENT1    RECENT2    RECENT3    RECENT4
Adam    10-Aug-16  02-Aug-16  15-Jul-16
Dave    19-Aug-16
Joe     19-Aug-16  12-Aug-16  10-Aug-16  26-Jul-16
Mike    19-Aug-16
Mike    19-Aug-16
Ryan    23-Aug-16  28-Jul-16
```

If there are more elegant solutions out there, I'd love to see them. Or, if someone knows how to fix the issue I'm having with more than one jump in a day, I'd love some input. Thanks.

Comment: Pretty sure your problem is at `AND DATE > jum.DATE`.  Changing to `AND DATE >= jum.DATE` should fix your issue.

Comment: @Breich I tried your suggestion, it didn't work. When I tried your edit on the query with `AND DATE >= jum.DATE) = 0;`, the query returned no records, and for `= 1/2/3` it shifted their results to the un-edited results of `= 0/1/2`, respectively.